# jQuery: How do I deal with self-closing tags and multiple loops?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 arrays: one with a list of cities, one with a list of states (which correspond to the cities), and one that's just a list of states with the duplicates removed.

I'm trying to generate a list that looks like this:

> - State 1
>
>   - City 1
>   - City 2
> - State 2
>
>   - City 3

Here's what I've got:

```
$.each(stateArrayUnq, function(i) {
    $('#list').append("<li>" + stateArrayUnq[i] + "<ul>");
    $.each(stateArray, function(j) {
        if (stateArray[j] == stateArrayUnq[i]) {
            $('#list').append("<li>" + cityArray[j] + "<\/li>");
        }
    });
    $('#list').append("<\/ul><\/li>");
});
```

I know I **can't** structure my code like this without having the browser auto-close my tags prematurely, but unfortunately I don't have the slightest idea how to rebuild this. I've read through a few related threads, but I'm still pretty confused. I think I'm supposed to set the "append" code to variables or something, but I don't know how to handle the loops.

I appreciate any help you can give. Thanks a bunch!

UPDATE: Here are my arrays:

```
var cityArray = ["Concord", "Lafayette", "Lewisville", "Madison", "NW Freeway Houston", "North Miami", "Casselberry", "South Fort Myers", "SW Freeway", "Woodbury", "Tarpon Springs"]
var stateArray = ["North Carolina", "Louisiana", "Texas", "Wisconsin", "Texas", "Florida", "Florida", "Florida", "Texas", "Minnesota", "Florida"]
var statearrayUnq = ["Florida", "Louisiana", "Minnesota", "North Carolina", "Texas", "Wisconsin"]
```

Comment: Build up the content as a big string and then do a single `.append()` when it's finished.

Comment: Can you include a small example of what your three arrays might look like? There may be a cleaner way to accomplish this.

Comment: Yup, I just added an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by building an html string which is stored in a variable. When you are done with your logic you can append the build html string.

```js
//Test data
var cityArray = ["Concord", "Lafayette", "Lewisville", "Madison", "NW Freeway Houston", "North Miami", "Casselberry", "South Fort Myers", "SW Freeway", "Woodbury", "Tarpon Springs"];
var stateArray = ["North Carolina", "Louisiana", "Texas", "Wisconsin", "Texas", "Florida", "Florida", "Florida", "Texas", "Minnesota", "Florida"];
var stateArrayUnq = ["Florida", "Louisiana", "Minnesota", "North Carolina", "Texas", "Wisconsin"];

//Generate the html string and append it.
var html = "";

$.each(stateArrayUnq, function(i) {
  html += "<li>" + stateArrayUnq[i] + "<ul>";
  $.each(stateArray, function(j) {
    if (stateArray[j] == stateArrayUnq[i]) {
      html += ("<li>" + cityArray[j] + "<\/li>");
    }
  });
  html += "<\/ul><\/li>";
});

$('#list').append(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list">
  <p>test</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, I think I get it now. It didn't occur to me that the code you write to a variable wouldn't be affected by auto-closing. Thanks!

Comment: If you write it to a variable it is stored as a string, not as html elements. Therefore there is nothing to close yet. The auto closing happens when the html code is parsed by the browser. The html is invalid so most browsers try to automatically fix that. I think (although not sure) that this behavior is even added to the w3 html specification.

Answer (score 1):

If `list` were a `ul`, you could nest them using actual jQuery objects like so.

```js
var cityArray = ["Concord", "Lafayette", "Lewisville", "Madison", "NW Freeway Houston", "North Miami", "Casselberry", "South Fort Myers", "SW Freeway", "Woodbury", "Tarpon Springs"];
var stateArray = ["North Carolina", "Louisiana", "Texas", "Wisconsin", "Texas", "Florida", "Florida", "Florida", "Texas", "Minnesota", "Florida"];

var data = cityArray.map((c,i) => ({state: stateArray[i], city: c})); //flatten the data
var $list = data.reduce(($ul, item) => {                              
  var $cityLi  = $(`<li>${item.city}</li>`);                      //Create <li> for city
  var $stateLi = $ul.children(`li[data-state='${item.state}']`);  //Find state <li>

  if (!$stateLi.length)                                           //Create state <li> if it doesn't yet exist
      $stateLi = $(`<li data-state='${item.state}'>${item.state}<ul></ul></li>`);

  $stateLi.children("ul").append($cityLi).end().appendTo($ul);   //Add the city to the state
  return $ul;
}, $("<ul />"));

$("body").append($list);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```